# Is there a way to compute this nested sum efficiently?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I came across this problem while coding. I was wondering if there is an easy way to compute the following expression:

for a set of $n$ values $a_1 \le a_2 \le ... \le a_n \le A$, calculate

$$\sum_{k_1=0} ^{a_1} \sum_{k_2=k_1} ^{a_2}\dots\sum_{k_n=k_{n-1}} ^{a_n} 1$$

Now this looks quite intimidating but I was thinking that there might be a relatively fast way of calculating it. Specifically I'd need something for $n = 7$ and $A = 52$

Comment: You can certainly get a recursion.

You can get a recursion. If $f_n(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is your sum, then:

$$f_n(a_1,\dots,a_n)=\sum_{i=0}^{a_1} f_{n-1}(a_2-i,\dots,a_n-i)$$ But that doesn't look any easier. I guess it somewhat avoids recalculating sums, if you cache them. Basically, the value inside the sum for $k_i$ is the same no matter what $k_1,\dots,k_{i-1}$ are.

Comment: How fast do you need it to be? For the specific case of $n=7,A=52$, efficient C code can compute the worst case ($a_1=52$) in about one second without shortcuts. Using a formula to evaluate the last two $\Sigma$, much like @Thomas's answer suggests, reduces this to less than 20 milliseconds.

Comment: There is a closed formula for $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_{n-1}=a,$ and $a_n=b\geq a.$ namely $\binom{a+n}{n}+(b-a)\binom{a+n-1}{n-1}.$

Answer (score 1):

I'm doubting you will be able to find a closed formula, but there is a divide and conquers approach which might at least simplify the computation.

For example, if $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5$ are the values, then we can count how many $1$s come from each $a_3=k.$

If we write $f_n(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ for your sum, then for each $0\leq k\leq a_3$ we'd get $$f_2(\min(a_1,k),\min(a_2,k))$$ pairs of values for $k_1\leq k_2\leq k$ and $$f_2(a_4-k,a_5-k)$$ for the number of pairs $k\leq k_4\leq k_5,$ giving:

$$f_5(a_1,\dots,a_5)=\sum_{k=0}^{a_3} f_2(\min(a_1,k),\min(a_2,k))f_2(a_4-k,a_5-k)$$

This lets you divide and conquer.

This will be faster than doing it sequentially, I'd guess.

For example, $$\begin{align}  f_5(1,2,3,4,5)=&f_2(0,0)f_2(4,5)\\
&+f_2(1,1)f_2(3,4)\\&+f_2(1,2)f_2(2,3)\\&+f_2(1,2)f_2(1,2)
\end{align} $$

We easily get, for $a\leq b,$ $$f_2(a,b)=\frac{(a+1)(a+2)}2+(b-a)(a+1)$$

---

In general, you might choose to select $k=\lceil n/2\rceil$ to divide the sequence in half.

But there might be some trick to do knowing the $a_i$ that makes finding a better $k.$

---

Since $f_1(a)=a+1,$ we also get:

$$\begin{align}  f_3(a_1,a_2,a_3)&=\sum_{k=0}^{a_2} (1+\min(k,a_1))(1+a_3-k)\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{a_1} (1+k)(1+a_3-k)+(1+a_1)\sum_{k=a_1+1}^{a_2}(a_3+1-k)\\
&=(1+a_3)\cdot \frac{(a_1+2)(a_1+1)}2 +(a_1+1)(a_3+1)(a_2-a_1)-\frac{(1+a_1)(a_2-a_1)(a_1+a_2+1)}2-\frac{a_1(a_1+1)(a_1+2)}3
\end{align} $$

You can factor this as:

$$(a_1+1)\left(\frac{(a_2-a_1)(2a_3-a_1-a_2+1)}2 +\frac{(a_1+2)(3a_3-2a_1+3)}6\right)$$

This comes out as the correct thing when $a_1=a_2=a,a_3=b,$ $\binom{a+3}{3}+(b-a)\binom{a+2}2.$

If $a_1=a,a_2=a_3=b,$ then you get:

$$\binom{a+3}3+\frac{(b-a)(b+3)}{2}$$
This is still a polynomial of $a_1,a_2,a_3.$

If there is a polynomial for $f_7,$ it can be got by breaking $\sum_{k=0}^{a_4}$ up into $$\sum_{0\leq k\leq a_1}+\sum_{a_1 <k\leq a_2}+\sum_{a_2<k\leq a_3}+\sum_{a_3<k\leq a_4},$$ and I suspect you will get a very messy polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add an optimization based on Thomas's solution, which would be helpful if $a_i$ differ from each other. Using his notation, we can perform the following: (as an example for $n=3$)

\begin{align*} f_3(a_1,a_2,a_3 ) &= f_3(a_1,a_2,a_2)+(a_3-a_2)f_2(a_1,a_2) \\ 
&= f_3(a_1,a_1,a_2)+(a_1+1)(f_2(a_2,a_2)-f_2(a_1,a_2))+(a_3-a_2)f_2(a_1,a_2) \\ 
&= f_3(a_1,a_1,a_1)+(a_2-a_1)f_2(a_1,a_1)+(a_1+1)f_2(a_2,a_2)\\
&\quad+(a_3-a_2-a_1-1)(f_2(a_1,a_1)+(a_2-a_1)f_1(a_1)) \end{align*}

We can do the same for larger values of $n$, but the expression will become less elegant. This sort of homogenises the upper limit of the sums.